# Separar Parte Entera y Parte Decimal de número Double C#

Tags: c#, números-enteros

¿Alguien sabe alguna idea de separar la parte entera de la parte decimal y convertirla ambas partes en parte entera?, es decir:

Tengo el número `Double 2500.16`, al separarlo debe quedar dos números (2500 y 16):

```
Double numero = 2500.16;
string numtext = numero.ToString(); 
string[] textSplit = numtext.Split(".");
entero = textSplit[0];
decimal= textSplit[1];
```

Pero el inconveniente es que al convertir el string a número entero que terminen en 0 (cero),
no son detectados, es decir, los números `10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90` estos lo detecta sin el 0.

Alguna idea de como puedo corregir esto.

Comment: Hablas de los números que no tienen decimales? De hecho no es necesario convertir en decimales, agregalo en un `var entero=textsplit[0]; ` y haz una validación primero `if(textsplit.count>0)` ahí pones tus dos variables, si no tiene decimales solo tomarás el primer Split

Comment: se me refiero a cualquier numero pueda separa cada parte, el problema es los numero decimales que terminan en cero.
me refiero que no es lo mismo 2500.10 ( dos mil quinientos con diez ) que 2500.1 (dos mil quinientos con uno)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

si quieres separar los números enteros y decimales, pueden hacerlo de esta manera, pero ten en cuenta que en un número entero sus decimales serán `**00**`

```
Double numero = 2500.16;
var decimalnumber = String.Format("{0:0.00}", numero);
string numtext = decimalnumber.ToString();
string[] textSplit = numtext.Split(".");
string numeroEntero = textSplit[0];
string numeroDecimal = textSplit[1];
Console.WriteLine($"mi numero entero es {numeroEntero}");
Console.WriteLine($"mi numero decimal es {numeroDecimal}");
```

una opción es formatear, para que el número solo tenga dos decimales, usando `String.Format`, en caso de que tengas un número entero y no decimales, quedara de esta manera `**2500.00**`, en este caso ya no es necesario hacer una validación con un if, porque el decimal siempre será `00` para números enteros

aquí puedes ver él [resultado del ejemplo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lLsiyV)

el resultado obtenido sera esto

```
mi numero entero es 2500
mi numero decimal es 16
```

Comment: exelente muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @Fredy Juárez Si te sirvió la respuesta, te recomiendo que la califiques como aceptada, también un recorrido al sitio para que puedas mejorar en como realizar una buena pregunta, esto nos ayuda a entender lo que necesitas y darte una mejor solución

Answer (score 1):

Para separar la parte entera y la decimal puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
Double numero = 2500.16;
Double parteEntera = Math.Truncate(numero);
Double parteDecimal = numero - parteEntera;

Console.WriteLine(parteEntera);
Console.WriteLine(parteDecimal);
```

Aquí se hace uso de la **función Truncate**, la cual trunca el número decimal y obtiene la parte entera del número, para obtener la parte decimal siguiendo este algoritmo lo único que hay que hacer es restar el número original, con el número ya truncado. Posteriormente imprimimos el resultado obtenido.

Comment: pero al usar `Math.Truncate(numero);` te redondea el decimal quedando de esta manera  `0.159999999999854` , creo que no es la manera correcta de hacer la separación

Comment: @Daniel, todo eso se resuelve, convertir un numero a string, y aplicarle el split es costoso, ademas que sucede si el separador es una coma o un punto en dependencia del idioma

Answer (score 1):

Veo que esta pregunta ya tiene respuesta, pero también puedes hacer un cálculo para obtener los decimales:

```
 internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Double numero = 2500.16;
        Console.WriteLine($"Numero={numero}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Decimal={GetDecimalPart(numero)}");
    }

    public static int GetDecimalPart(double numero)
    {
        int decimalPart = 0;
        decimalPart = (int)(((decimal)numero - (int)numero) * 100);
        return decimalPart;
    }
}
```

Esto va a funcionar con 2 decimales, se podría agregar más lógica en caso de que se quieran manejar más decimales, y toma en cuenta que esta es solo otra forma de hacerlo, no estoy segura cuál es la diferencia de performance entre convertirlo a string o realizar solo cálculos, pero aquí está otro ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

**Intenta lo siguiente:**

```
int IntNumero;
int IntDecimal = 0;
Double numero = 2500.1;
string numtext = numero.ToString();
string[] textSplit = numtext.Split(",");

IntNumero = Convert.ToInt32(textSplit[0]);

if (textSplit[1].Length > 1)  
    IntDecimal = Convert.ToInt32(textSplit[1]);

if (textSplit[1].Length == 1) 
    IntDecimal = Convert.ToInt32(textSplit[1]) * 10;

Console.WriteLine($"Numero: {IntNumero} - Decimal: {IntDecimal}");
```

**Test:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota: Por temas del idioma o la región, puse `numtext.Split(",")` con `coma (,)`, ya que no me agarra el punto en los decimales.

Comment: Cuidado con ese ToString(), ya que dependerá del CultureInfo del ordenador si el separador es punto o coma. Lo suyo sería utilizar el CurrentCultureInfo y el separator en cuestión

Comment: me parece exelente creo que realizare un conteo al double y un conteo despues del tostring y comparar ambos y agregar un 0 si esto es diferente